# Close look at the OS: Running a presentation on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I'm running a presentation on Windows 8. I'd like to show a close look at the minute features on the OS, is there any command or in-built tool available to show what's happening closely?

There may be a magnifier, but I'm looking at the entire screen zooming in. Not just a tiny zoomed in bar on top.

Comment: Just do whatever you would do on Windows 7.  Your queston is not clear, what is, "minute feature" exactly?

Comment: Referring to a close view of the tools, menu, tiles. Sorry if that wasn't clear. And this is my first Win OS after XP. I've been on ubuntu so long.

Comment: I'm also unclear as to what you're asking.  You literally just want to zoom the image?  Then you'll need to use the magnifier (or 3rd party software to do the same thing, I guess) or a lower resolution or a larger screen.  Can you please be more explicit about what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry it is unclear. I'm looking for a solution similiar to magnifier. But magnifier shows part normal view and part zoomed view. I just want it full zoomed view while I demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making presentations, I used ZoomIT

Download link: [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx)

Please check if this suits your purpose. The site says it's XP and higher, so it must work on Win8 too, you might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 there is a new keyboard shortcut: you can pressthe Win key and the Plus key (win+) to zoom in and the Win key and the Minus key (win-) to zoom out